# How to access the global environment in R using rpy2 in Python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to access a dataframe from R global environment and import it into Python in Pycharm IDE. But, I am not able to figure how to do it.

I tried the following:

Since, I don't know how to access the global environment where my target data.frame is stored. I created another R script (myscript.R) where I converted to data.frame into a rds object and called it again.

```
save(dfcast, file = "forecast.rds")
my_data <- readRDS(file = "forecast.rds")
```

However, when I try to read the rds in python using the following code in Python:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage

cwd = os.getcwd()
pandas2ri.activate()
os.chdir('C:/Users/xx/myscript.R')
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('forecast.rds')
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
df.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'forecast.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Please show the way to deal with this. I just want to access a data.frame from R in Python.

The data.frame is actually a forecast generated from another R script which takes about 7-8 minutes to run. So, instead of running it again on Python , i want it to process in R and import the forecast dataframe to python for further analysis. Since, I am in the midst of building further analysis module. I don't want the R forecast function to run again and again while I am debugging my analysis module. Hence, I want to directly access it from R.

Comment: Seems like a path issue. It cannot find the file. Please check whether the file is actually in the right path.

Comment: @nicola does it need to be the path where the script is or the directory where all the R files are stored?

Comment: Neither, all paths are relative to your working directory, you can get your working directory in R with `getwd()`